# libGDX - how to remove existing spritebatch on screen?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I've been looking through and experimenting some stuff but can't quite get how to remove pre-existing spriteBatch on screen.

so basically
I have initiated

```
batcher.begin();
(blah blah blah)
AssetLoader.font.draw(batcher, "Hey guys", x, y);
```

something like this... 
now I wish to delete/remove/undraw this thing on screen...
how do I do that without using if statement because.. if I start using If statements everything is going to get sooo messy.

Thanks so much!

Comment: you can use `dispose();` method

Comment: @user3225831 If he disposes an asset he will get a null pointer exception when the code wants to draw again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its generally accepted practice in an OpenGL application to clear the screen every time and re-draw the entire screen.

So, to "erase" something, you just stop drawing it.

```
boolean wantToSeeThis = true;

...

void render() {
   batcher.begin();
   (blah blah blah)
   if (wantToSeeThis) {
       AssetLoader.font.draw(batcher, "Hey guys", x, y);
   }
}

void hideIt() {
   wantToSeeThis = false;
}
```

Comment: to stop drawing, do you mean that i should stop rendering it? I have only one rendering class atm. Does this mean that I should create more rendering class? @P.T. Thank you!

Comment: @HyunwooLim I've updated the example in my answer to make it clearer how to 'stop' drawing something.  (There are an infinite number of ways to express this, so just take this as one suggestion...)

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit unclear what you are asking. By default your screen gets cleared every frame with this line in the `Render` method.

```
gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
```

Then obviously we need statements of when we want to draw things. If you code your whole program in a single class this obviously gets messy quick. But Java is `OOP` which means you can add a classes with there own `Draw`/`Render` method and there own statements as to when they should be drawn. I suggest you start learning the basics of `OOP`.